# Running order of multiple scripts in an HTML document?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML page that i ship to the browser and it contains a couple of script tag.

This is my `index.html` file:

```
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>

    <script src="src/index.js"></script>

    <script>
      window.test = true;
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And this is my `src/index.js` file:

```
<script>

const test = () => {
  if (window.test) {
    console.log("wow!");
  }
};

test();
</script>
```

In the HTML file, i define `window.test` **after** i run the `src/index.js`.
`src/index.js` will only print to the console if `window.test` is set to `true`, but that's being set only after, as the second script.

What is the order in which these scripts will run?
Is there a guarantee that `window.test` will **always** be set to `true` "just in time" for the `if` statement in `src/index.js` to print `wow!`?

CodeSandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/javascript-forked-utgh8?file=/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to guarantee that test function is only call after variable is setted why not use a custom event

```
<script src="src/index.js"></script>

<script>
  window.test = true;
  const event = new Event('test-setted');
  document.dispatchEvent(event);

</script>
```

and in index.js

```
<script>

const test = () => {
  if (window.test) {
    console.log("wow!");
  }
};
document.addEventListener('test-setted', function (e) { 
    test(); 
}, false);

</script>
```

Comment: Is the running order of multiple scripts not guaranteed?

Comment: with this solution the order is not an issue (your are not dependent of the order of different script) while you don't receive the event the function is not run

Comment: Yes I understand and thanks for it, I'll definitely try it. I was just wondering in general how the executive order is determined.

Comment: I understand the best i can give you is the specification of script order https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#the-script-element 

the specification say it is executed in the order where it is include

Comment: but my advice is if you have to "synchronize" several scripts it's better to use promise, event and other mecahnism that don't need a certain order to succeed

Comment: Interesting.. I do really wonder why they don't run in order If that's the specification. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In JS called from HTML file the order of the scripts are just like their order of writing in this file "always" will be in that order, which means that in your example `window.test` Will always have a null value in `index.js` so nothing will be printed in the console

Comment: That's not the case though, it is always printed: https://codesandbox.io/s/javascript-forked-utgh8?file=/index.html